# Many to many relation association Issue

Tags: ruby, console, associations, has-many-through, ruby-on-rails-6

I have two models of User and Lottery having a relation of many to many through a bridge table Lotteries_Users class name LotteriesUser.

Here are those models:

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lotteries_users, class_name: "LotteriesUser"
  has_many :lotteries, through: :lotteries_users
end
```

lottery.rb

```
class Lottery < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :lotteries_users, class_name: "LotteriesUser"
    has_many :users, through: :lotteries_users
end
```

Lotteries_User Model: lotteries_user.rb

```
class LotteriesUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :lotteries
end
```

I tried using class names after has_many relation but its still not working.
I am getting an error of 
**NoMethodError (undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for Users:Module)** on rails console *Lottery.first.users*

and
**NoMethodError (undefined method `last' for #)** on rails console 
*User.first.lotteries*

Comment: Why do you decide to use `class_name` in this case? How your migration/schema look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just name your model and table according to the conventions and it will all just click:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lottery_users
  has_many :lotteries, through: :lottery_users
end

# table should be named lottery_users
class LotteryUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user # should be singular
  belongs_to :lottery # should be singular
end

class Lottery < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lottery_users
  has_many :users, through: :lottery_users
end
```

Improper naming can cause a lot of issues since Rails will look for `Lotteries::User` if the table is named `lotteries_users`. When deriving class names from table names it assumes that plural words are namespaces.

The convention for join models is SingularSingular unless there is actually something more discriptive like for example `Ticket` or `Entry`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer. It worked. I am new to rails and still working on basics.